# Expand Environmental Variable from runtime generated variable name

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, delayedvariableexpansion

I have created a batch file that alters the PATH depending on what compiler name I pass to it.  I also want to select from a number of these variables at runtime, I have another batch file where I generate the name of the appropriate environmental variable to look at, but I can't see how to expand the generated variable

e.g

```
EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%
```

so when the batch file is called the environmental variables _1 and PLATFORM expand to produce sections of the naming convention for the name of the variable I want to expand

if I call `echo EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%` this would produce the name of the variable I want to expand

How can I go from the generated name, to the contents of the environmental variable with that name?

I suspect delayedexpension is required but I'm not sure

Comment: `call echo %%EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%%%`or `call echo EXE_PATH_%%%_1%_%PLATFORM%%%`. It's a bit unclerar to me.

Comment: @JosefZ the first one works

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you mean, but here is most likely the information you need:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "_1=VSC"
set "PLATFORM=x64"
set "EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%=%ProgramFiles%\VSC\bin"
set "EXE_PATH_NAME=EXE_PATH_%%_1%%_%%PLATFORM%%"
set "EXE_PATH_NAME=%EXE_PATH_NAME%"
set EXE_PATH_
endlocal
```

This batch code outputs for example:

```
EXE_PATH_NAME=EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%
EXE_PATH_VSC_x64=C:\Program Files\VSC\bin
```

It is necessary to use **CALL** to expand the variables in value of `EXE_PATH_NAME`, i.e. use this batch code with one more line according to comment by [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) which sets variable `EXE_PATH_VALUE`:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "_1=VSC"
set "PLATFORM=x64"
set "EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%=%ProgramFiles%\VSC\bin"
set "EXE_PATH_NAME=EXE_PATH_%%_1%%_%%PLATFORM%%"
call set "EXE_PATH_NAME=%EXE_PATH_NAME%"
call set "EXE_PATH_VALUE=%%EXE_PATH_%_1%_%PLATFORM%%%"
set EXE_PATH_
endlocal
```

This batch code with additional `call` outputs for example:

```
EXE_PATH_NAME=EXE_PATH_VSC_x64
EXE_PATH_VALUE=C:\Program Files\VSC\bin
EXE_PATH_VSC_x64=C:\Program Files\VSC\bin
```

But I really don't understand why making this so complicated.